# how to find bad disk in raid array?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-5, clicking-sound

I have a RAID5 array and one of the disks clicks whenever I start up the array. During array operation, it seems to run fine though. This has me worried that I'm going to start running into problems later on down the line with that HDD having a problem initializing its heads or whatever is causing that clicking noise.

So whats the best way to find the culprit disk without losing any of the data on my array?

Answer (score 0):

You could check SMART state of the disks either by running a utility or checking log files if you have SMART monitoring service running. The clicking should be definitively captured as SMART event. You did not specify what operation system you are running, so I cannot be more specific.